# button:after content that appears on hover shifts down when you move mouse off button

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

I have a button where content (the arrow) in the :after selector appears after the button is hovered over. The content (the arrow) appears but when I move my mouse off of the button it shifts down for a split-second before it disappears. I'm wondering why this is happening and if I can make it to where it stays in one position vertically the whole time.

Tried to edit top to offset the adjustment but it does it no matter what

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/mklingcoding/pen/vYvGwgr

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    /* Sets 1rem equal to 10px, 2rem equal to 20px, so on */
    font-size: 62.5%;
    background-color: #4731D3;
}

#projects-btn {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 200px;
    background: none;
    color: #CBF281;
    border: 1px solid #CBF281;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    transition: all 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#projects-btn:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font: var(--fa-font-solid);
    content: "\f178";
    color: #CBF281;
    padding-left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
  
#projects-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#projects-btn:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button id="projects-btn">Projects</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour was because you gave `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to `#projects-btn:hover`. Either you can remove that or add `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` to `#projects-btn`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    /* Sets 1rem equal to 10px, 2rem equal to 20px, so on */
    font-size: 62.5%;
    background-color: #4731D3;
}

#projects-btn {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 200px;
    background: none;
    color: #CBF281;
    border: 1px solid #CBF281;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    transition: all 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#projects-btn:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font: var(--fa-font-solid);
    content: "\f178";
    color: #CBF281;
    padding-left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
  
#projects-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#projects-btn:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button id="projects-btn">Projects</button>
```